# Convergence of Newton's method when minimizing a strongly convex function

Tags: convex-optimization, newton-raphson

If I have a multivariate function f twice differentiable which is strongly convex, and smooth as well, so $\mathit \nabla ^2f - \mu I$ and $\mathit LI - \nabla ^2 f$ are both positive definite at every point, does the Newton's method to find its minimum always converge ?

Intuitively, I feel like this is true, but I can't find any proof of it.

So far my research did not lead anywhere. The documents I found either focused on finding a root instead of the minimum, or the function used was convex but not strongly.

Thank you for your help

Comment: see https://www.di.ens.fr/~aspremon/PDF/MVA/UnconstrainedEquality.pdf slide 22. The short answer is yes, it always converges.

Comment: In your document, they say that the newton algorithm needs backtracking to converge, so I guess that implies that the newton algorithm on its own is not necessarily able to converge ?

Comment: No, eventually you enter the regime where you are quadratically convergent anyways and the step size is constant there even under adaptive step size schemes.

Comment: @TSF This proof also assumes that \nabla^2 f is Lipschitz continous. Is it possible to prove convergence without this assumption (possibly with a worse rate of convergence)?